# deriving $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}\cdots} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to derive $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}\cdots}$ at $x=6$ ?

Comment: Hint: find a better expression for $y$.

Comment: please note that this an algebra question, not a derivatives question.

Comment: Were you trying to do L'Hospital?

Comment: @chubakueno Will that really help? If yes, how? Where is 0/0 or $\infty/\infty$ form?

Comment: @puru Hehe no, I thought that you found this in a larger limit problem and tried tu use L'Hospital there(because of the strange derivation question)

Answer (score 3):

$y^2=x+y\implies y^2-y-x=0$ For $x=6$, $y^2-y-6=0\implies y=3$ or $y=-2$.

$y$ can't be negative, hence $y=3$.

Comment: You want the value of $y$ at $x=6$ or the derivative of $y$ at $x=6$?

Comment: I think 'derive' here means find the value, as in, come up with a derivation. If you wanted a derivative, the correct verb would be 'differentiate' and not 'derive', although this confusion is made often enough that it's nice to have a clarification.

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted the word 'derive' as 'to find the value' and not 'to find the value of the derivative'. Thanks @AlexZorn for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First you want to rewrite $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}$ in a friendly form. To do this note that $y=\sqrt{x+y}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

> $$\begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> y=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}\cdots}\Leftrightarrow 
> y^2&=6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}\cdots}, \\&=6+y.
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$$

Hence:

> Find  $y$ in $$y^2-y-6=0.$$

Use the following: $y^2-y-6=(y-3)(y+2).$

Hence: $y=3$ or $y=-2$.

Since, $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}\cdots}\geqslant0$ then $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}\cdots}=3.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you square both sides:

$$y^2 = x + y$$

If x = 6:

$$y^2 = 6 + y$$
$$y^2 - y -6 = 0$$
$$(y-3)(y+2) = 0$$
$$y = 3, -2$$

Since y cannot be negative, y = 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

$$
y = \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x + \cdots } } } },
$$

means to *"repeat up to infinity"*.

---

So we write

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y_0 &=& 0,\\
y_{n+1} &=& \sqrt{ x + y_n },\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and we define

$$
y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n.
$$

We must first show that $y$ exists.

---

---

If $y$ exists we obtain

$$
y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_{n+1}
\Rightarrow y = \sqrt{x+y} \Rightarrow y^2 - y - x = 0 $$

At this point the quadratic formula tells us that $$y = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x}}{2}$$
and we take the positive solution.

The case $x=6$ yields $y = \tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} \times 5 = 3$.